# Yii2 - How to set checkbox to be checked and saved in settings by default?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, backend

Hello guys i have problem with checkboxes i must set it by default to be checked , other guy programmed this and i'm new on this code so if someone know how to fix this i will be grateful.

Here is my code:

````
use app\settings\SettingsModel;
use app\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use youdate\widgets\ActiveForm;
use trntv\aceeditor\AceEditor;

/** @var $elements array */
/** @var $title string */
/** @var $subTitle string */
/** @var $model SettingsModel */

$message = \Yii::$app->session->getFlash('settings');
?>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title"><?= Html::encode($title) ?></h3>
    </div>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
    <div class="card-body">
        <?= $this->render('/_alert') ?>

        <?php if (isset($subTitle)): ?>
            <h4 class="mb-5"><?= Html::encode($subTitle) ?></h4>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ($elements as $alias => $element) {
            if (is_callable($element['type'])) {
                echo $element['type']($model, $alias);
            } else {
                switch ($element['type']) {
                    case 'dropdown':
                        echo $form->field($model, $alias)
                            ->dropDownList(is_callable($element['options']) ? $element['options']() : $element['options'], [
                                'prompt' => Yii::t('youdate', '-- Select --'),
                            ])
                            ->hint($element['help']);
                        break;
                    case 'checkboxList':
                        echo $form->field($model, $alias)->checkboxList($element['options'])->hint($element['help']);
                        break;
                    case 'checkbox':
                        echo $form->field($model, $alias)->checkbox(isset($element['options']) ?: [])->hint($element['help']);
                        break;
                    case 'code':
                        echo $form->field($model, $alias)->widget(AceEditor::class, ArrayHelper::merge(isset($element['options']) ? $element['options'] : [], [
                            'mode' => 'php',
                            'containerOptions' => [
                                'style' => 'width: 100%; min-height: 200px'
                            ]
                        ]))->hint($element['help']);;
                        break;
                    default:
                    case 'text':
                        echo $form->field($model, $alias)->hint($element['help']);;
                }
            }
        } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('youdate', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php $form->end() ?>
</div>```
````

I tried to use something like this :

````
```$model->$alias= true;
echo $form->field($model, $alias)->checkbox(isset($element['options']) ?: [])->hint($element['help']);```
````

I achieve to set checkbox to be checked by default but i think that info must be stored in background session to take effect so that only works if i click Submit button but i want to store it without clicking the button.

So i will share some codes bellow that is included by this file..
Code for SettingsAction:

````
```<?php

namespace app\settings;

use app\traits\RequestResponseTrait;
use app\traits\SessionTrait;

/**
 * @package app\settings
 */
class SettingsAction extends \yii\base\Action
{
    use RequestResponseTrait, SessionTrait;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $category;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $viewFile;
    /**
     * @var array|callable
     */
    public $viewParams = [];
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $items;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $settingsManager = new SettingsManager($this->category, $this->items);
        $settingsModel = SettingsModel::createModel($this->items);
        $settingsModel->setAttributes($settingsManager->getSetting($settingsModel->getAttributes()));

        if ($settingsModel->load($this->request->post()) && $settingsModel->validate()) {
            $settingsManager->setSetting($settingsModel->getAttributes());
            $this->session->setFlash('settings', 'Settings have been saved');
            return $this->controller->refresh();
        }

        $viewParams = is_callable($this->viewParams) ? call_user_func($this->viewParams) : $this->viewParams;
        $viewParams = array_merge($viewParams, [
            'settingsManager' => $settingsManager,
            'settingsModel' => $settingsModel,
            'items' => $this->items,
            'title' => $this->title,
        ]);

        return $this->controller->render($this->viewFile, $viewParams);
    }
}```
````

Also here is code for ActiveField:

````
```<?php

namespace youdate\widgets;

use app\helpers\Html;

/**
 * @package youdate\widgets
 */
class ActiveField extends \yii\widgets\ActiveField
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $labelOptions = ['class' => 'form-label'];

    /**
     * @param array $options
     * @param bool $enclosedByLabel
     * @return \yii\widgets\ActiveField|ActiveField
     */
    public function checkbox($options = [], $enclosedByLabel = false)
    {
        $options['class'] = 'custom-control-input';

        if (!isset($options['uncheck'])) {
            $this->parts['{uncheck}'] = Html::hiddenInput(Html::getInputName($this->model,$this->attribute), 1);
            $options['uncheck'] = false;
        } else {
            $this->parts['{uncheck}'] = 'true';
        }

        $this->template = '
            {uncheck}
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                {input}
                <span class="custom-control-label">{labelText}</span>
            </label>';

        $this->parts['{name}'] = $this->attribute;
        $this->parts['{labelText}'] = $this->model->getAttributeLabel($this->attribute);

        if (isset($options['value'])) {
            $this->parts['{value}'] = $options['value'];
        } else {
            $this->parts['{value}'] = $this->model->{$this->attribute};
        }

        return parent::checkbox($options, $enclosedByLabel);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $options
     * @param bool $enclosedByLabel
     * @return ActiveField
     */
    public function radio($options = [], $enclosedByLabel = true)
    {
        $this->labelOptions['class'] = 'custom-control custom-radio';
        $this->parts['{customInput}'] = Html::activeRadio($this->model, $this->attribute, [
            'class' => 'custom-control-input',
            'label' => false,
        ]);
        $this->radioTemplate = "<label class=\"custom-control custom-radio\">{customInput}<div class=\"custom-control-label\">{labelTitle}\n</div></label>\n{error}\n{hint}";

        return parent::radio($options, $enclosedByLabel);
    }

    /**
     * @param null $label
     * @param array $options
     * @return \yii\widgets\ActiveField
     */
    public function label($label = null, $options = [])
    {
        if ($label !== null) {
            $this->parts['{labelText}'] = $label;
        }
        return parent::label($label, $options);
    }
}```
````

There are many more files that are connected with checkboxes and the Setting form, but I think these are the most important

Answer (score 0):

As per you code:

- `)->checkbox(isset($element['options']) ?: [])` options are passsing vie `$element['options']` where one of the array element can be `'checked' => 1`
- or you can hardcode `)->checkbox(['checked' => 1])`
- even based on come condition let say, name of your field, you can merge `$element['options']` and your hardcoded `['checked' => 1]` where checked will be overwrited.
- one options also inside `case 'checkbox':` block , set `$model->$alias = true`

Comment: That works visually too but no actual effect until i press Save button, so goal is to make it checked and saved at the same time.

Comment: Does you tried with the latest way as well? $model->$alias = true

Comment: Yes, i have tried everything but i think problem is in session storing or something like that, when checkbox is set to checked that need to be stored somewhere in session i think... if that is the case i think i will need to share here code from other files as well, whad do you think ?

Comment: I added codes from other importat files that is connected to this problem, please check it.

Comment: Seems in your code is overwriting checkbox and `uncheck` is set to be check as state. You can try above codes but except checked => 1, try uncheck => false or reverse.